# Rails tagging gems/plugins: Is there a way to do weighted tags?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, taxonomy

I'm interested in using acts-as-taggable-on for a Rails 3.x app:
https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

Doing a quick search for other tagging solutions, this seemed like one of the better-supported ones. But I didn't see (at least in the introductory readme) for a way to do weighted tags.

For instance, if I have a Place model and I wanted to tag "Bob's Pub" with "bar, American, beer, cozy"...I'd like "bar" to be the tag that best defines "Bob's Pub". This would be in lieu of having a category field.

But now that I think about it, that would seem to add quite a bit of overhead, perhaps even an extra column or table to handle and store that kind of calculation. Am I right in guessing that a "weighted tag" is not of particular practical use?

acts-as-taggable-on does have contexts...so when assigning tags to an object, I could set a "primary_list" of tags which would contain several of the most important tags that define the object.